# Windows Store App (JavaScript) stopped displaying embedded web fonts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, webfonts

We use javascript/Angular inside our application and have a few different typefaces saved into a fonts folder within the project.

During a recent update the app stopped loading/displaying multiple fonts for no reason and with no alerts/errors.

The splash screen is taking considerably longer now as well so I assume it's related.

I reverted the code to before the edit and the issue persist.

I thought it may be visual studio so I upgraded to 2015, still has the problem.

I've done a ton of reading and I cant seem to figure out what would cause the webfonts not to load, hoping someone has some insights because I'm at a bit of a dead end.

Comment: I won't know anything about windows store apps but if you are saying that it is now taking longer to load that makes me think that the fonts are being loaded from someplace that doesn't exist anymore.  So it takes a long time because it is waiting for a response and then just times out and you see the default fonts.  So maybe whatever method/url was used to load the fonts isn't available anymore.

Comment: Jose, Not a bad theory but unfortunately not the case. I added fonts to a specific folder and they wont load. I also purposely renamed the file and it fired the "missing file" alert so it is loading the files but not displaying them. 

It's like when web apps would take forever to load a font file so the browser would load the default fonts and then when they'd load correctly switch back (FOUT) but it's never switching...